# Persist data between requests invisible from the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's my problem: I want to show the user a hash from a random number, then that user has to guess if the number is higher or lower than a certain treshold. After the game, I want to show him the  number so he can verify that the number has not changed during play.

But how do I do that? I have thought about using Redis to store the random number and the user id in there, but it seems like there are easier solutions.

Thanks!

Edit: In the end I chose Redis because it's server side only for maximum security and I may find some additional uses for it.

Comment: But then the user can simply look at the cookie and win every game.

Comment: You can crypt the value, why don't you want to use redis? Fast and relaible.

Comment: Crypting the value would cost a lot of speed as the server has to decrypt and encrypt the value again. I don't want to use redis, because I think redis is to powerful for that simple task. It's like taking a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: why wont you encrypt and store it in the db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a "signed" cookie. This prevents the user to "look" at it, and gives no overhead

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

To write:

```
cookies.signed[:guess] = guess
```

To read:

```
cookies.signed[:guess]
```

Comment: I did not know about those, thanks. How safe are they? I can't find that much information about them.
Edit: But couldn't the user save the cookie and then send the cookie with the next game to get the same number as before?

Comment: They are safe in that a user can't "read" them. They could copy, but, by deleting any "pending" cookies before you start a new game, by deleting it immediately after he "solved" the game, you should be pretty save